# hi there, why the while loop don't continue to -infinity and stop on -1

Tags: javascript

Why don't continue the while loop until -infinity?

```
 <script>
        var number=[100,3,250,99,70,1,70];
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=maxValue(number);
        function maxValue(arr){
        var len=arr.length;
        var min=Infinity;
        while(len--)
        {
          if(arr[len]<min){
            min=arr[len];
          }
        }
          return min;
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: you can use devTools to debug your code and understand what is happening, then you can identify by yourself

Comment: `while(len--)` it means it's going to loop n times where n is the array length, not infinity

Comment: `len--` will reduce until `0`, then, basically while will check `while(0){...}` 0 is false, then while stops

Comment: When len becomes 0 it becomes false so your while(false) will obviously not run

Comment: in javascript, boolean value of 0 is false. so when len becomes 0. the loop breaks. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp

Comment: thank for answer i get my answer in R.S comment, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It uses the condition of the [`while` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) with the value of `len` and if it is zero, then the iteration stops, because this value is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

The following decrementing changes `len`, but has no influece anymore of the condition, because of its postfix nature of the [decrement operator `--`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement).

```js
function maxValue(arr) {
  var len = arr.length;
  var min = Infinity;
  while (len--) {
    console.log('len', len);
    if (arr[len] < min) {
      min = arr[len];
    }
  }
  return min;
}

var number = [100, 3, 250, 99, 70, 1, 70];

console.log(maxValue(number));
```